# Store RLMFile into array in Realm swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, realm

I Want to store `RLMFile` into `RLMArray`. Is there any way to perform this task.
If there is no way than Please tell me How can i store multiple images of property.`This application based on storing properties and rooms available.`

Comment: What is a RLMFile? That is not a type defined by Realm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RLMFile` isn't a type defined by Realm. You can store binary files directly inside Realm as `NSData`, but this isn't recommended since you don't get any gains over simply saving the file to disk (and it also inflates the size of the Realm file).

It depends on what you want to do, but the easiest solution is to keep your images on disk, and then save their filenames/fileroutes to Realm. You would create a Realm object that saves the file name, and then each of these objects could be saved to the `List` property of a parent Realm object.